# Microservices autorization issue(passport js)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, passport.js, monorepo

I recently started a course on microservices and ran into a problem with the application of the passport. The problem is that my strategy apparently does not see my token and does not call the validate method. After reading the articles, I realized that this may be due to the fact that my token is not valid and his time ran out, but I checked this case. I will leave all the photos of my services, the structure below. I will also add a link to git. Thank you in advance

JWTStrategy seems like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2rx1.png)

My login method(rmq):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I46GY.png)

App module:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHdTg.png)

RMQ service:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU82d.png)

problem like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaY91.png)
link to github: [click](https://github.com/Mark-blip-star/microservice-rmq-backend) .

Comment: github branch - master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For JWTAuthGuard to work, you need to add a call to the fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken function in [jwt.straragy.ts line 11](https://github.com/AlariCode/6-microservices-demo-1/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/strategies/jwt.straragy.ts#L11):

```js
// from:
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken,
//to:
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
```

2. add import JwtStratagy to api [app.module.ts](https://github.com/AlariCode/6-microservices-demo-1/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/app.module.ts) providers array

```js
providers: [JwtStrategy]
```

3. And the decorator @UserId() does not work correctly. It returns a user object but should return user.id from request.user. For @UserId decorator to correct work, you need to change [line 4 in user.decorator.ts](https://github.com/AlariCode/6-microservices-demo-1/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/guards/user.decorator.ts#L4):

```js
// from:
return ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()?.user;
//to:
return ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()?.user?.id;
```

My issue with same answer:
https://github.com/AlariCode/6-microservices-demo-1/issues/1

My implementation:
https://github.com/Rudimo/nx-nest-microservices-rmq-demo